# Преобразовать одномерный/двумерный массив в строку длинной не более 60 символов

Tags: php

Возможно ли преобразовать одномерный/двумерный массив в строку длинной не более 60 символов с возможность в дальнейшем преобразовать получившуюся строку обратно в массив?

Comment: Есть масса способов (например serialize или json_encode). А вот на счет 60 символов - это от массива зависит, может у вас в нем текст войны и мира записан, который в 60 символов ну никак не влезет

Comment: Это на самом деле XY проблема. Что у вас за массив и почему именно __60__ символов?

Comment: ограничение на длину post параметра такое

Comment: вот приблизительный вид массива(может быть 2-3 доп параметра) $test_array = array('user' => 'customer', 'user_id' => '1', 'service_for_pay' => array('1', '2', '3'));

Comment: Что за ограничение? Кто его создал? Видно же что оно явно не подходит.

Comment: вот: https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/payment-buttons/reference/forms-docpage/ ограничение длины поля label 64 символа

Comment: Ну так создайте у себя таблицу заказов, вносите в нее данные, а в яндех передавайте ИД заказа.

Comment: во первых заказов для оплаты  может быть много, во вторых мне нужно передавать дополнительные параметры такие как: id пользователя и тип пользователя

Comment: как это лучше передавать?

Comment: Вы понимаете, что яндекс-деньгам __параллельно__ на ваши ИД пользователя и тип пользователя? Все что им надо это номер кошелька. Так зачем вы передаете в ЯДеньги всю эту инфу? Храните ее у себя на сервере в таблице, в яденьги передавайте номер заказа. По номеру заказа у себя найдете инфу - ид пользователя, тип пользователя, что угодно.